# What is the best video/textual source for learning circuit designing? I want to create a high amplitude, function generator?

Tags: power-electronics, function-generator, tutorial

I am a self taught software programmer, I have an electrical engineering project where I have to design a function generator of high voltage/amplitude using 555 timer. The function generator that I have seen on e-commerce websites are very expensive and also of low voltage/amplitude.
I tried looking for some basic electrical engineering tutorials on Youtube, Udemy, and other sources, they teach the concepts for the purpose of college exams, however I want to learn for the purpose of building a machine. I know the working principle of electronics component but I don't know how to check and calculate their units to put them into the circuit.

My requirement is as follows: I want to supply DC to a transformer, so I want to convert the DC to high voltage AC where I can control the voltage & current (at primary coil), frequency upto 1MHz or 100 Mhz (if easy), and at secondary I want to rectify the output and convert it into 50 Hz AC where I can control the voltage and current.

Can you suggest a source of video or textual tutorials that will teach me to design a circuit after teaching basic concepts and formulae?

Comment: Video tutorials are one of the worst ways to learn this.

Comment: @DKNguyen textual tutorials will also help, please suggest them

Comment: I'm afraid GHz design is also beyond me. This is basically RF design. I've not seen this as tutorials because there is too much background knowledge required first. You should be covering the regular analog stuff first. https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/linear-circuit-design-handbook.html Note that you don't build a GHz function generator to save money over buying one.

Comment: You have to learn how to crawl at 10 MHz before you can walk at 100 Mhz then run at  1 GHz as the circuit rules with impedance and capacitance change the designs significantly.   I assumed you haven't learnt to crawl yet. in design competency and transmission line theory with linear architecture and PCB materials and layout

Comment: You may want to consider picking up a textbook, rather than a patchwork of random tutorials. Any circuit analysis text -> Sedra/Smith -> Razavi texts get you there; Razavi's RF Microelectronics is also great if you want to go into high-speed stuff. There really is no shortcut around it.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=hp+sig+genrator+tear+down&qpvt=hp+sig+genrator+tear+down&FORM=VDRE&msclkid=6fe170d8a88f11ec9e45a22f8e6179fb

Comment: It sounds like you want to build a DC to AC inverter for a 50Hz power line frequency -- that is (A) a solved problem, and (B) may involve switching frequencies into the hundreds of kHz, and _maybe_ into the low single-digit MHz, but certainly won't be efficient above that with today's transistor and transformer technology.

Comment: @TimWescott no, I am building a different type of transformer, and I need to supply power to its primary coil, I want to evaluate the output power at secondary at various values of current, voltage & frequency at primary coil, so I want to ability to tune the current, voltage and frequency of primary; once I get the maximum output, I'll note down the values and build a permanent circuit on PCB for that transformer.

Comment: @Yogie "I am building a different type of transformer" Typically any topology you can come up with has been figuratively beaten to death already and there's a ton of papers with example designs and whatnot. Look at publications of any academic power electronics research center, there are several in the US alone. You may find out quickly that there are better ideas out there than what you had in mind. Don't expect that your idea will be novel just because you thought it. It may be, but >99% of the time it won't be, at least not without some domain knowledge.

Comment: @Yogie But I'm at a bit of a loss for why would you build such a thing, when you can buy powerful, dirt-cheap class D audio amplifiers... just use one to drive a 50/60Hz transformer and you're done. For a one-off, it'll work pretty well, and you can easily add digital closed loop control with nothing more than an Arduino Mega - to compensate for variable load level and lower the effective output impedance.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I am building an alternate flux path transformer where back emf flux from secondary (on load) doesn't couple back with primary, it couples with 2nd secondary, I am trying to replicate this: https://patents.google.com/patent/US20140253271A1/en I can wind the coil, fetch the core, laminate it, calculate max current as per core size, all I need to build is a circuit to control (tune) input voltage, current & frequency from 1Hz to some 10MHz to find the most optimum input values. Please review that patent, and comment your views.

Comment: @Yogie You may stop right here. That's a patent for a "free energy device" that should not have been awarded in the first place. Don't waste your time. There's a reason why you don't "tune" such devices: you design them to work they way you want them to first. There's no transformer that will work from 1Hz to 10MHz in any way that is useful in power applications. A 100W 1Hz transformer will be about as big as a 2-3kVA 60Hz transformer. This follows basic design equations. No need for tuning. Nothing here needs new discovery. It's old stuff. Centuries old now!

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica thanks for your suggestion! I don't want to talk about the topology of the transformer, I can take care of it, all I need is to build a function generator supporting high amplitude, and I need to learn just enough to achieve my goal, I don't want to learn to become an electrical engineer, once I make the prototype and convince my investor, i can hire electrical engineers to take care of rest of the stuff. Please suggest a tutorial which can teach me the circuit design. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because author admits that the work is meant to potentially defraud investors by putting together a "free energy" device.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica hahaha! investors are smart, their fleet of renowned electrical engineers will examine the device, there are other such devices that exists on earth, watch this news coverage -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrIJi5DEREo

Answer (score 1):

It's completely unnecessary to do this at 100MHz, and also quite wasteful in terms of energy losses and design effort. 1MHz will be plenty, since it's a frequency about 20,000 times higher than the fundamental of 50Hz. There'll be no problem filtering out the PWM noise from the output signal.

The 555 timer generates a square wave, so you'll need a sine-shaper circuit to convert it to some facsimile of a sine wave, and then use that to drive a PWM running at 100kHz..1000kHz. I suggest starting at 100kHz.

> I need to supply power to its primary coil, I want to evaluate the output power at secondary at various values of current, voltage & frequency at primary coil, so I want to ability to tune the current, voltage and frequency of primary

Why would you run the transformer in a resonant circuit with its uncontrolled parasitic capacitances? Because that's what you'd be testing. That's the only reason you'd "test" the transformer for any sort of a "maximum": you'd be getting a resonance, and as soon as you'd load the transformer, this resonance would get damped. Transformers generally speaking have a fixed voltage ratio, and as long as you're not driving it too fast nor too slow for the core size & material, it'll work very similarly no matter the frequency within that range.

But you shouldn't be "testing" stuff before you design it. The procedure is, very approximately, as follows:

1. Select the maximum power you need at the output. Add some factor of safety, say 50%.
2. Tentatively select drive circuit topology and secondary rectifier/filter. Estimate their losses. Increase the power passed through the transformer to compensate for the losses as needed.
3. Select an operating frequency based on the available core materials *and* on the switching losses of the mosfet you'll use to drive the core. This will be a compromise. You'll need to buy cores from an actual specialist manufacturer, no random stuff unless your time is worthless to you.
4. For a given power and primary DC voltage, calculate the amp-turns you need on the primary. Then select the core cross-section so it won't saturate.
5. Calculate the core losses at the drive frequency, drive waveform, and flux level.
6. Design the primary winding based on the operating frequency and current. You may need to use a Litz wire, i.e. multiple smaller diameter wires in parallel, to combat the skin effect.
7. Design the secondary winding.
8. Calculate winding losses. Go to step 2 if they exceed the allowance you gave yourself.
9. Estimate/model the thermal performance to ensure that the whole thing doesn't suffer thermal runaway at the highest operating ambient temperature you chose.
10. Design the drive circuit and any feedback you need. Model the control loop - this can be done incrementally using spice software, without necessarily doing all the math by hand. But you'll need to at least develop some intuition about how the controller behaves as you tweak the forward and backward path through the control loop.
11. Design the secondary rectifier/demodulator and filters.
12. Based on the secondary losses, refine the power that needs to be driven into the primary, and
13. Order parts. Assemble the prototype. Test to confirm that real performance is close to predicted performance. If not, backtrack, find mistakes or assumptions/models that were too simplistic, refine, and repeat.

You will not need to check at what frequency you get best output: the equations you'll derive for the losses will all be functions of frequency, so you can select the frequency for best efficiency ahead of time. You can tune it a to get maximum efficiency based on experimental data, but this won't be in terms of "highest output", just "lowest losses". Your circuit should deliver the power you need, or else your design process has failed somewhere and you'd need to figure it out and redo/fix the design. The output will be controlled in a closed-feedback loop, although you can get reasonable performance even open-loop, but the output impedance won't be super low.

Testing is pretty much the last step in the process. Now, you can definitely do incremental design where you test your assumptions and understanding at a more granular level. But that typically requires test equipment that you trust that can be used to, say, drive the transformer with a 1MHz square-wave without you first building a driver. That way you could ensure that your understanding of the transformer design is adequate before moving to putting together the drive and output circuits. You can claim understanding when you're able to make a design that works more-or-less as you have expected it to. Any discrepancies point to a need for a deeper investigation/learning.

You'll definitely want to start with lower voltages, lower power levels, and perhaps slightly lower frequencies as well. The design of your final "product" will take several times shorter if you precede it by progressively larger designs as you explore the limits of your understanding.

And the testing isn't something that you can do with no tools. The rather bare-bones budget you'd need for test equipment and lab gear needed to actually evaluate such a design is $5k if you have enough experience to know exactly what you'll need and where to get it cheaply, or twice that if you just want to buy a bunch of stuff from Rigol or Siglent and call it a day. Due to often unexpectedly high voltage levels encountered in circuits with significant inductances, you may destroy test gear if you're not careful. Always have your nominal voltages a factor of 3-5x away from the maximum voltage ratings of the test eqipment - until you get enough experience to know that no unexpectedly high spikes will occur.

In my experience, just the probes and accessories needed to safely measure the inductor circuits without blowing up your scope will cost 1-5x the power level. E.g. a 1000W supply may call for $2-$5k in probes alone, if you don't want to be rolling your own.

Of course all this could be achieved for much less money, but then you'll have to learn how to design your own test tools: power supplies, current sensors, AC amplifiers, etc. If you have the time rather than money, you'll have to go that route.

Do not let all this discourage you! It's not an infeasible task. It will help you to know what it takes, though.

And be very wary of extrapolating from low-power designs: they "scale", but the attention to parasitics and energy losses becomes much more critical the higher you go in power. I don't know what your target power level is, but just know this: having a couple hundred Watt-capable power supply circuit release the magic smoke and shrapnel in your face is not some remote possibility. It'll happen less often if you start small, so that the inevitable mistakes, shorts and runaways will be less spectacular as you learn. Once you're at 100W level, put a sheet of perspex between you and the device, unless you like snacking on plastic from the cases of the power devices, tantalum oxide and electrolyte from capacitors :)

Answer (score 0):

I have quite rightly been chastised by The Powers That Be for suggesting a commercial product, which is against the house rules.

So all I can say is that Horowitz and Hill have done some excellent work in this area, covering the theoretical and practical aspects of electronic design.

Comment: Is it written in a layman terms? Is it comprehensive enough for a software guy to learn and build stuff?

Comment: No, it is not written in laymen's terms -- but by the time you can do what you need to do, you won't be thinking in laymen's terms.  Get the book and study.  As you run into stuff you don't understand, backfill.  It _is_ comprehensive -- it is (or was) the textbook for a sort of all-in-one practical electronics course taught at MIT to physicists.

Comment: @jayben Please remember that recommendations for specific products are off-topic on this site. As long as AoE is not free to the public it is a "product".